# Connect RETOOL to locally-hosted postgres database

Tags: postgresql, retool

I am trying to connect Retool to a postgres database running on my local machine.

The connection string looks something like this:

```
postgresql://USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost:5432/application?schema=public
```

When I try to connect to it using retool, I get this error:

> Unable to connect. Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

The docs say something about whitelisting Retool's IP addresses, but I am not sure how to do that.

Thank you!

EDIT: I am running the self-hosted version of Retool using Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `host.docker.internal` as host instead of `localhost`